# Shell Script : How to add in the end of lines which contains special string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, grep

I have a VAR which contain :

```
list_data="toto
titi
tata
tete"
```

My array can contain like this example or more values then 3 data :

```
arraytest[0]="Hello|Test|env|tata|POLO|GER|GO|"
arraytest[1]="GOODNIGHT|Test2|env2|tete|GOLF|ITA|NOTGO|"
arraytest[2]="AFTER|Test3|env3|JAJA|CIT|FRA|GO|"
```

and my string is

```
string="INSERT"
```

What I want to do is to add special string in the end of each line where every line contain each value of list_data

For example :

```
arraytest[0]="Hello|Test|env|tata|POLO|GER|GO|INSERT"
arraytest[1]="GOODNIGHT|Test2|env2|tete|GOLF|ITA|NOTGO|INSERT"
arraytest[2]="AFTER|Test3|env3|JAJA|CIT|FRA|GO|"
```

I try this

```
echo ${arraytest[*]} | sed -i 's/$/ $string'
```

Please Help.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe share your code so we can help you.

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for 
tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: echo ${arraytest[*]} | sed -i 's/$/ $string'

Comment: Sorry shellter but i'am a beginner in shell coding that why i don't share my code :(

Comment: You seem to be asking about your specific approach to solve a problem you have, but maybe the approach isn't the best in the first place. Can you describe the underlying problem better? Are you really required to work with an array, or do you have the input in a file somewhere, and using an array is what you've come up with so far?

Comment: Why doesn't `arraytest[2]` in the 'after' have a `|INSERT` at the end?  Typo in question?  Serious requirement?  (If the latter, you need to do a lot more explaining!)

Answer (score 1):

**`bash`** solution:

```
string="INSERT"
pat="(${list_data//$'\n'/|})"
for i in "${!arraytest[@]}"; do 
    [[ "${arraytest[$i]}" =~ $pat ]] && arraytest[$i]+=$string
done
```

---

The final `arraytest` contents:

```
echo ${arraytest[*]}
Hello|Test|env|tata|POLO|GER|GO|INSERT GOODNIGHT|Test2|env2|tete|GOLF|ITA|NOTGO|INSERT AFTER|Test3|env3|JAJA|CIT|FRA|GO|
```

---

Details:

- `pat="(${list_data//$'\n'/|})"` - constructing regex pattern(`pat` contains `(toto|titi|tata|tete)`)
- `${!arraytest[@]}` - the basic signature format is `${!name[*]}` - if *name* is an array variable, expands to the list of array indices (keys) assigned in *name*.

Comment: Nice. You could also write `pat=${list_data//$'\n'/|}` and `arraytest[$i]+=$string`

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the individual elements of the array (rather than ${array[*]} )

```
    for ((i=0 ; i<${#arraytest[*]} ; i++))
      do
           echo ${arraytest[${i}]} | sed "s/$/|${string}/"
     done
```